# Drag Gesture issue because of Tap Gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a Contact Row View where you can tap on the row to bring up another screen or swipe left to reveal a delete button behind the view.

The drag gesture lags when I first move it and it's very noticeable (even more than the gifs). However, when I remove the tap gesture, it works smoothly.

How do I get the drag gesture to stay smooth while keeping the tap functionality on the row?

This is the drag gesture lagging when there's a tap gesture. Notice how it skips when it first moves to the left and then again when it first moves to the right.

[image]

And this is when I remove the tap gesture:

[image]

Here's the code:

```swift
struct ContactRowView: View {
    
    @State var isSwiped: Bool = false
    @State var swipeOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // View behind the row
            Color.red
                .cornerRadius(8)
            
            // Delete button (behind row)
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .font(.callout)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 90, height: 50)
                }
            }
            
            // Contact Row
            HStack {
                Text("Name")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .background(
                Color.blue
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.1), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 2)
            )
            .offset(x: swipeOffset)
            .overlay(
                Color.clear
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .padding(.leading, 50)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Tapped Row")
                    }
            )
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onChanged(onChanged(value:)).onEnded(onEnd(value:)))
            
        }
        .frame(height: 44)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    func onChanged(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        if value.translation.width < 0 {
            if isSwiped {
                swipeOffset = value.translation.width - 90
            } else {
                swipeOffset = value.translation.width
            }
        } else {
            if isSwiped {
                swipeOffset = value.translation.width - 90
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onEnd(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        withAnimation(.easeOut.speed(2)) {
            if value.translation.width < 0 {
                if -value.translation.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2 {
                    swipeOffset = -1000
                    print("DONE SWIPE")
                } else if -swipeOffset > 50 {
                    isSwiped = true
                    swipeOffset = -90
                } else {
                    isSwiped = false
                    swipeOffset = 0
                }
            } else {
                isSwiped = false
                swipeOffset = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to ask... instead of implementing this yourself... are you able to use this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/swipeactions(edge:allowsfullswipe:content:)

Answer (score 0):

I do concur with the suggestion to not implement it yourself and potentially switch to use lists. However, if that's not possible, you could try the following:

I see you have your tap on the overlay and the drag on the HStack. Could you try combining the two using an `Exclusive` gesture? More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing-swiftui-gestures

In particular, you could try:

```
gesture(TapGesture(count: 1)
        .onEnded{ _ in
            // Tap gesture action
        }
        .exclusively(before: DragGesture()
            .onChanged { _ in
                // perform drag
            }
        )
```

In the example, the TapGesture will take precedence if the UI detects both. Give it a try, and if it's not performing the way you want, i'd flip the order of DragGesture and Tap so that Drag is performed exclusively before the Tap.